# Conditions under which a group homomorphisms between products of groups arises as a product of homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory

Let $\phi: G\times H\to G\times H$ be a group homomorphism. Under what conditions can we write $\phi=(f,g)$, where $f:G\to G$ and $g:H\to H$, where $f$, $g$ are group homomorphisms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi : G \times H \to G \times H$ is determined uniquely by its values on the natural embeddings of $G$ and $H$, since $\phi(g,h) = \phi(g,1) \phi(1,h)$.

We restrict $f$ to these natural embeddings to get functions $f_G : G \to G \times H$ and $f_H : H \to G \times H$. Then the function $(f_G, f_H) : G\times H \to G \times H$ defined by $(f_G, f_H)(g,h) = (f_G(g),f_H(h))$ agrees with $\phi$, so is equal to $\phi$.

So, all the time.

Comment: I was hoping for a non-trivial factorization, and hence i wrote under what conditions. The above factorization depends on the given $\phi$. I think it is too much to ask for a non trivial factorization, i am sure many counterexamples exist. Was wondering if existence on non trivial factorization has been investigated.

Comment: Well, you gave $\phi$ in your question, which determines $(f,g)$ as a I showed. Maybe if you phrase what you are looking for a little more precisely you can get the answer you are looking for.